# DataStax Enterprise throwing errors when Kerberos is enabled

Tags: kerberos, datastax-enterprise

The following error keeps showing up:

```
ERROR 12:39:10,529 PriviledgedActionException as:cassandra/datastax3.mytest.org@MYTEST.ORG cause:org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: GSS initiate failed
INFO 12:39:10,529 Initiating logout for cassandra/datastax3.mytest.org@MYTEST.ORG
INFO 12:39:10,529 Initiating re-login for cassandra/datastax3.mytest.org@MYTEST.ORG
WARN 12:39:13,009 Auth failed for 170.173.220.222:56765:null
INFO 12:39:13,009 IPC Server listener on 8012: readAndProcess threw exception javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Encryption type AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96 is not supported/enabled)]. Count of bytes read: 0
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Encryption type AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96 is not supported/enabled)]
at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Server.evaluateResponse(GssKrb5Server.java:177)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Connection.saslReadAndProcess(Server.java:1007)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Connection.readAndProcess(Server.java:1180)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener.doRead(Server.java:537)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener$Reader.run(Server.java:344)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Encryption type AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96 is not supported/enabled)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:788)
```

Original post: http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/topic/error-message-in-systemlog-with-kerberos-enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AES 256 is not supported by JVM by default. You need to install unlimited strength cryptography extension first to enable AES 256.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html

Thanks to Piotr for the original answer.

Comment: It is supported but disabled.